# Is it possible to single out a json object and set it as another object only using JSTL?

Tags: jstl

I'm new to Jstl. Hope this question is not a duplicate.

Say, if there's a json object like below,

`jsonObj = {"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null}`

what I would like to do is take `"John"` from `name` and set it as value for `userName`.

So what I tried is `<c:set var="userName" value="${jsonObj}.name" scope="page" />`.

If I print `userName` with command `<script>console.log(${userName})</script>`, I can see `John` on the console panel.

However, if I look through the Sources in developer tools, I find that whole jsonObj value showing on every objects that I created from jsonObj.

Am I asking for something that's not available?
If not, any advice would be grateful no matter how small they are.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`<c:set var="userName" value="${jsonObj}.name" />` is equivalent to something like:

```java
userName = jsonObj.toString() + ".name";
```

Assuming `jsonObj` is an [`org.json.JsonObject`](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html), you can access the content of your Json with:

```html
<c:set var="userName" value="${jsonObj.getString('name')}"/>
```